# Using Fn::Join with a "Ref"

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm at a roadblock with this one, I've been trying to find a way to simplify my work so as to avoid using a giant if statement block. I came to the idea that I could use s "Ref" With a `"Fn::Join"` but obviously it doesn't work or at least not the way I'd visually think it would work.

```
"Type": "AWS::WAFRegional::Rule",
"Properties":{
"Predicates": [{
"DataId":{
"Ref" : {"Fn::Join" : ["", [{"Ref" : "IpSets"}, "IPSet"]]},
```

So how I visually see this working is that `"Ref" : IpSets` is a parameter that we set when uploading the file to CloudFormation. So it will pull down that text, and combine it with IpSet to create something like DevIPSet. Since that's a String after a join, it would come out to be "Ref" : "DevIPSet" and then that would pull the set of IP's I've put aside.

This obviously doesn't work and was reaching out to the community if there is a trick I can use. I have looked into Mapping and can't see to make that work with the dataID either. The only real solution I've found is just using `Fn::If` and make a giant block but that is ugly.

Comment: I think you should post a more complete example, not just bits an pieces. Also an example of how your giant `Fn::If` block looks like.

Comment: So this code sits inside the  Predicates of  `AWS::WAFRegional::Rule` and is a complete example of the code I've written but didn't work. 

The Fn::If is just 8 if statements inside each other. 

`"Fn::If" : [ "Prod", {"Ref" : "ProdIPSet", {"Fn::If" : ....` 

The Ref to a Join was what I thought of to remove the massive condition statement but obviously it doesnt work.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have problems with.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding me and the question. 

I already posted the code that I had written and didn't work, and was looking to the community for solutions or if it's not possible.

Comment: @FubarP where is the IPSet data coming from? Are they inputs? Mappings? Other resources?

Comment: Can you better explain what you are trying to accomplish rather than asking for syntax help?  I’d like to help but I don’t understand what you are actually trying to achieve

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please explain what you are actually trying to achieve - and include your complete code. I'd like to see your *giant `Fn::If`* block.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do, I think, is not possible. Because there is a **duplication of tag property**.